# "File not found" error when running program found on network drive

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to create a VBScript that runs a program found on a public drive. It's not working.

I have:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run """Z:\pathname\file.exe"""
Set WshShell = nothing
```

Where pathname and file are where the file is found...
I'm getting the following error:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
```

The path name and file name are both correct, so that's not the error. I can start this through `cmd.exe` without any problems after changing the director to the `Z:` drive, so why this is happening when I try to run it through VBScript?

Comment: That is not a VBScript error message. Most likely explanation: the program you're trying to start is looking for a file in the current working directory, which is most likely not `Z:\pathname` when you start it from your VBScript.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there a way to start a shell object in another directory or to change its directory?

Comment: You can verify that by running `cd /d C:\ & Z:\pathname\file.exe` from a command prompt.

Comment: I know that you can do this through a command prompt, but I'm hoping to do this through VBScript. Is this possible?

Comment: The above command is to verify my hypothesis.

Comment: You can just type 
    `Z:\pathname`
and then
    `file.exe`
in cmd.exe to open the file. How can you change the working directory of a shell application in VBScript, though?

Comment: If it works through cmd then you shouldn't have to change anything about the program. If it works in cmd after changing the current directory to Z: then just do the same in your script: `WshShell.CurrentDirectory = "Z:\"` and then run your program.

Comment: Please read carefully. I told you to `cd` to ``C:\``, **NOT** ``Z:\``, and then run the program **with its full path.** If that does not throw the same error, then my hypothesis was wrong and changing the working directory won't help. So would you **PLEASE CHECK IT?!**

Comment: thanks, eurotrash. That's what I was looking for.